# How do I remove the recurring header Chapter and Number in USTHESIS?

Tags: header-footer, thesis

I'm new to LaTeX, I'm using it to write my Doctorate Proposal with USTHESIS package (Stellenbosch University).

I need to remove the chapter and chapter number that re-occurs as header.

The previous answers for the formats for book or report didn't work properly, only

```
\pagestyle{myheadings}
```

works, but it leaves the word CONTENTS in my header. How do I remove this?

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
   \markboth{}{}
```

or use

```
   \pagestyle{plain}
```

if you want the page numbers at the bottom of the page.